# I have a completed transaction that when I open the dash never was completed and it never went through since 11/11/21 IT SAYS DROPPED TRANSACTION?

Tags: pending-transactions

I have a completed, succeed, transaction that when I open the dash it says dropped?

Comment: I believe you have txid and explorer showing no information, If this is the case then there is something wrong with the transaction `nonce` value, All the transactions going out from a particular address should be in a increasing sequence starting from 0.

Comment: What wallet are you using? What's the transaction hash?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.